# A differentiation question on differences between calculating it through 2 ways

Tags: derivatives

What is result of differentiation of $y=\sqrt{ 25-x^2}$ and why it’s different when calculating differential of implicit function $x^2+y^2=25$?

Comment: Well, the first one is only the upper half the circle of radius $5$ whereas the second equation is the full circle of radius $5$. It should give you the same $\frac{dy}{dx}$ everywhere where the derivative is defined, but the derivative on the lower half circle is simply minus the derivative on the upper half circle since $\frac{d(-y)}{dx}=-\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiating $x^2+y^2=25$ gives $2x+2yy'=0$ which is the same as $y'=\frac{-2x}{2y}$.

Differentiating $y=\sqrt{25-x^2}$ gives $y'=\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{25-x^2}}$ which is the same as before?